# (Java) Trying to print "abc" 5 times with a return statement

Tags: java, string, parameters, return

Here is the homework:

> Write a method called `printStrings` that accepts a String and a
>   number of repetitions as parameters and prints that String the given
>   number of times with a space after each time.
>
> ```
> printStrings("abc", 5);
> ```
>
> will print the following output:
>
> ```
> abc abc abc abc abc
> ```

This is what I have tried:

```
public class Apples {

    public static String printStrings(String a) {

    return (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        System.out.print(a);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printStrings("abc"));
    }
    }
}
```

Really don't know what to do.

Comment: You honestly should put a little more effort from your side into this... the above code isnt even valid -.-

Comment: I'm new. I've been trying.

Comment: 1. Google "How to java" 2. Read docs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public static String printStrings(String a,int b) {
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
        s=s+a+" ";    

    }
    return s;
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(printStrings("abc",5));
}
```

Comment: `return (int i = 1; i <= b; i++)` what is this I don't even...

Comment: please consider my edit one

Comment: Clearly this is a homework, please consider on pointing out where the OP is wrong, not just do the homework for him. What he learns this way?

Comment: its not whole code its jst code fragment that guide OP to build logic

Comment: This fragment will most likely not guide him..

Comment: @Narmer the same way all user giving there answer..please justify downcast

Comment: Th fact that everyone is making your mistake is not a good reason to do it yourself. You were the first to post this solution and the downvote is perfectly explained above. I was writing a similar comment on another answer, but the answerer had the good idea to delete his post.

Comment: Btw this _is_ the whole code. The OP asks for a method that prints the given strings. Which logic should he build after what you wrote? You also wrote the main. He only has to open eclipse and copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code a little

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printStrings("abc", 5));
}

public static String printStrings(String a, int numOfTimes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(""); // StringBuilder is better than concatenating Strings
    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfTimes; i++) {
        // System.out.println(sb);
        sb.append(a);  // append String 
        sb.append(" "); // append space
    }
    sb.replace(sb.length()-1, sb.length(), ""); // replace last space 
    System.out.println(sb.length()); 
    return sb.toString(); // return String representation of StringBuilder sb
}
```

O/P :

```
19
abc abc abc abc abc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printStrings(String a, int b) {
    String printString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<b; i++){
       printString = printString+" "+a;
    }

    System.out.println(printString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work, and it wouldnt put a space at the end:

```
private static void printStrings(String str, int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        System.out.print(str + (i == num - 1 ? "" : " "));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String printStrings(String a, int count) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
    {
        result = result + a;
        if (i != (count-1))
            result = result + " ";
    }
    return result;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(printStrings("abc", 5));
}
```